# Writing from container to host in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I currently have a job that runs a script. This script needs to create a file on the host file system.

To do so I make use of a hostPath volume with:

```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /var/logs/test
  name: joblogs
volumes:
- hostPath:
  path: /root/test
  type: DirectoryOrCreate
  name: joblogs
```

I used

```
 chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /root/test
```

to allow the writing on this directory, but even if files are created in

> /var/logs/test

they are not on

> /root/test

on the host.

EDIT: The pod itself runs on the same node I am talking about.

Comment: I'd recommend you to store the files on a cloud service instead. Would that be possible?

Comment: What OpenShift instance are you running this in? Is it a full multi node cluster, or are you using something like Minishift? In the case of Minishift the ``hostPath`` refers to a file inside of the VM created by Minishift and not your actual host file system.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton It is just a VM with an  Openshift instance running on it, so if the pod runs on the node itself it should be stored on this said node AFAIK.

Comment: First, the question: How many nodes do you have in this cluster? Second, I don't know about openshift, but in Kubernetes you can use "kubectl describe $volume" to get some details about volume.